# Getting user data from firebase realtime-database returns null

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I need help. When I register a user, user data are uploaded to a "user" table. On the main activity I am trying to get that data but there is an error

This is the mainActivity

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        phone = findViewById(R.id.profilePhone);
        fullName = findViewById(R.id.profileName);
        email    = findViewById(R.id.profileEmail);
        resetPassLocal = findViewById(R.id.resetPasswordLocal);

        profileImage = findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
        changeProfileImage = findViewById(R.id.changeProfile);


        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user");


        StorageReference profileRef = storageReference.child("users/"+fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()+"/profile.jpg");
        profileRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                Picasso.get().load(uri).into(profileImage);
            }
        });

        resendCode = findViewById(R.id.resendCode);
        verifyMsg = findViewById(R.id.verifyMsg);


        userId = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        user = fAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if(!user.isEmailVerified()){
           
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {


                    users_model user = snapshot.getValue(users_model.class);
                    String userName = user.getName();
                    String userPhone = user.getPhone();
                    String useremail = user.getEmail();

                    fullName.setText(userName);
                    phone.setText(userPhone);
                    email.setText(useremail);


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
      

        changeProfileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // open gallery
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),EditProfile.class);
                i.putExtra("fullName",fullName.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("email",email.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("phone",phone.getText().toString());
                startActivity(i);


            }
        });


    }
```

this is the model class

```
public class users_model {

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private String type;

    public users_model() {
    }

    public users_model(String name, String email, String phone, String type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

**this is the error**

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.firebase_auth, PID: 27880
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.firebase_auth.users_model.getName()' on a null object reference
at com.example.firebase_auth.MainActivity$3.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:126)
at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

[Firebase Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84qhd.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: Is your response 200? If yes, then the problem is with your users_model class. Your error says, that your response isn't parsed to your model class, that's why when you try to get the name (first value), it returns null. It probably doesn't match the structure of your db table. Post it, too. You may end up needing to use @SerializedName("model_param_title") for every users model param

Comment: I added a picture of the structure of the db table.

Comment: how to use @SerializedName